# Error: undefined is not an object Realm.Sync.setFeatureToken(token)

Tags: realm

I'm using realm with my react native project, and I want to sync my data to realm object server but when I tried to insert the token

```
const token = "token here";
Realm.Sync.setFeatureToken(token)
```

I got an error: undefined is not an object Realm.Sync.setFeatureToken(token);
What could be the problem with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setFeatureToken()` is used to enable Professional and Enterprise Edition features when using Realm from Node on the server. It is not present when using React Native because there is nothing to unlock on the client side.